# How to flush html to the user in GAE/PHP?

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Using PHP on Google App Engine - How do I send the html to the user and continue running the php script?

this is what I've been trying so far, but it doesn't work. The browser displays the page only after the entire script was executed:

```
ob_start();

$url = $_POST['url'];

$html = file_get_html($url);

echo $html;

ob_flush ();

// time consuming processing here...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do it - the response is only sent to the user once the script has completed.

If you want to do some processing after the response is sent the I suggest you use [task queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/taskqueue/).